# How to use data from a particular column from SQL Server and assign it to a variable in Python

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, pymssql

I wanted to retrieve data from a SQL Server row and assign the required columns to variables in Python.

Currently I'm using the code shown below to retrieve separate column data and assign it to variable. Is there any way to retrieve the whole row and use the required columns?

Code:-

```
#Sql Connection
conn=pymssql.connect(server='.', user='sa',password='abc@123',database='test_db')
#Get a
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('select a from tbl where status=%d','1')
aaa= cursor.fetchone()
#Get b
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('select b from tbl where status=%d','1')
bbb= cursor.fetchone()
#Get c
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('select c from tbl where status=%d','1')
ccc= cursor.fetchone()


xxx =', '.join(ccc)
yyy= ', '.join(aaa)
zzz=', '.join(bbb)
```